# Android widget with multiple color themes

Tags: android, android-layout

What is the best method to set a widget colors theme saved on SharedPreferences. Users choose their preferred colors theme and programatically I set the theme.

For example I have two styles for a TextView with id "widgetThemeDate":

```
<style name="widgetThemeDate" parent="@style/widgetThemeLight">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorWhite</item>     
</style>

<style name="widgetThemeDate" parent="@style/widgetThemeDark">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorBlack</item>     
</style>
```

In this case I receive the following error: "**error: Resource entry widgetThemeDate already has bag item android:textColor.**"

How can I set "widgetThemeDate" color depending user's choice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't set whole themes on a view programatically (see [this discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/88c53b8c790a750d?pli=1)), but you can change certain aspects progamatically. For instance. you case you could use the [setTextColor()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextColor%28int%29) method to change the color of text programatically on ay TextView.

Comment: I want to define the colors on styles.xml and programatically switch them to set the widget colors. Forget about the themes; Now I mean only to colors and switching them. How is the best way to do that.

Comment: I think the best way is to declare multiple widget.xml files (for example widget_black.xml or widget_white.xml) with different TextViews ids (for example android:id="@+id/widgetAMPMColorBlack" and set different styles in styles.xml.

Comment: Kurtis, check the result here: http://mogoolab.com/portfolio/android-flowers-clock-widget/ Thanks again.